# Rails 4 associate comment with blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a rails app with a Blog and comments, each blog post has many comments.  In each blog (show action) I can submit a comment on at form.  My question is I need to associate the blog_id in comments with the blog I am viewing, I could pass this as a hidden view but I am asking for the BEST way to do this, maybe a helper I am unaware of.

```
<h3>Leave a reply</h3>

<% @blog.comments.each do |comment| %>
 <p>
   <%= comment.text %>
 </p>

<% end %>


<%= form_for(Comment.new) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :blog %>


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize a new comment, initialize it through a blog instance.

```
  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @blog.comments.build
  end
```

Then, in your form, you want to use the comment instance instead of initializing a new comment:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
```

Assuming you have the correct relationships the comment will automatically have the blog id.

In the create action you will want to ensure the comment is also created through the blog instance.

```
  def create
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @blog.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      # etc ...
  end
```

Although associating a comment with a blog may not be a good design decision depending on what you want to do, unless by blog you mean a post.

Comment: When I click submit I am not passing the blog Id, do I do that explicitly?

Comment: You don't have to. the blog id should be in the params. Your resource should look like `/blogs/1/` <-- that one is the blog id. Use it to fetch the blog. Your routes would be `resources :blogs do resources :comments #...` <- This will ensure that comments are always constraint under a blog route. Check out the nested resources here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html